# ML.NET Model in .net framework

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

How can I use the model I generated with Ml.net Model Builder in .NET Framework?

I want to use my generated model with .NET Framework and I don't want to perform predictions in a console application. If possible, the entire process should take place within .NET Framework.

Comment: Do you want to use it on WPF, ASP or WinForm?, could be useful if you provide more context or information.